# How to check multiple String in a dataset in each row?

Tags: scala

I have the following arrays:

```
Array(book, chalk, book, eraser),  
Array(book, chalk, book, pen),  
Array(book, chalk, book, pencil),  
Array(book, chalk, chalk, eraser),  
Array(book, chalk, chalk, pen),  
Array(book, chalk, chalk, pencil),  
Array(book, chalk, eraser, pen)
Array(book, chalk, eraser, pencil),  
Array(book, chalk, pen, pencil)
Array(book, eraser, book, pen),  
Array(book, eraser, book, pencil),  
Array(book, eraser, chalk, eraser)
```

I want to remove Arrays having different Strings. E.g: `Array(book,chalk,eraser,pencil)` needs to be removed.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use:

```
val arr = Array(Array("book","chalk", "pencil","eraser"),Array("book","chalk", "book","pen"),Array("book","chalk", "book","pencil"),Array("book","chalk", "chalk","eraser"),Array("book","chalk", "chalk","pen"))

arr.filter(x => x.length != x.toSet.size)
```

Comment: Or `x.distinct` instead of `x.toSet` for a very tiny increase in clarity.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul as per Ajith's requirement, `toSet` is more suitable as `distinct` is a bit costlier (may not be significantly), because it maintains order as well.

Comment: `toSet` does not maintain order. It might in these examples, but it's not part of the contract. And order is irrrelevant if we only want the size.

Comment: Yes, that is my point. `distinct` maintains order but `toSet` does not. So I went with `toSet`.

Comment: OK. I agree it's more efficient, if that's the important aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of distinct, you can use simple custom function, that will be little bit more efficient, since it should not traverse whole array, if duplicate is in the beginning of an array:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

def hasDuplicate[T](arr: Array[T]): Boolean = {
  val seen = mutable.HashSet[T]()
  var seenBefore = false
  var i = 0
  while (!seenBefore && i < arr.length ) {
    val v = arr(i)
    seenBefore = seen.contains(v)
    seen += v
    i += 1
  }
  seenBefore
}

val input = Array(Array("book","chalk", "pencil","eraser"),Array("book","chalk", "book","pen"),Array("book","chalk", "book","pencil"),Array("book","chalk", "chalk","eraser"),Array("book","chalk", "chalk","pen"))
input.filterNot(hasDuplicate)
```